# Run-time Error 91, but I've got everything Set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro for Excel to grab data from different worksheets and put it onto a summary page. Because I'm new to `VBA` my current method is to search for "TOI Score" (always found in row 45), offset that cell by one column to the right, copy from that cell to `.End(xlDown)` and `.PasteSpecial` with the `transpose = true` at the bottom of that worksheet, then search for the next instance of `TOI Score` and repeat. Eventually it will copy the copied data to the summary page.

For some reason though, I cannot get Excel to find `TOI Score` within this particular script. I know that it can find it using a bare-bones macro that's only purpose is to find it, but I can't figure out what is messing it up in this one. At first it was simply not finding the string, but I did something and now I'm getting run-time error 91 (the one where it says I'm referencing a non-object or empty object). Thanks for any help you can give...

Here's the script up to where I get the error:

```
Sub GrabMyData()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim CopyRng As Range, CopyHere As Range, CopyHereLastCol As Long, CopyHereLastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range, fullRange As Range
Dim myLastRow As Long, myLastCol As Long
Dim Last As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim t As Long



On Error GoTo Err

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary Sheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Summary Sheet"


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        strSearch = "TOI Score"

        Set oRange = ActiveSheet.Rows(45)       

        Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        Lookat:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from around strSearch. Right now that's what you're searching for, not "TOI Score."

Comment: @DougGlancy OK I was getting the error before because of strSearch not being defined, but now I can't get it to find my string so aCell is always reported as undefined. It's driving me crazy because if I just pull out the code needed for the search, the search works, but in the context of this one I can't get it to find my strSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the worksheets and using the variable `sh` to store the current sheet. When you set the range to be searched using the variable `oRange`, you always look on the active sheet and not on the sheet specified by `sh`

Try changing:

`Set oRange = ActiveSheet.Rows(45)`

to:

`Set oRange = sh.Rows(45)`

Comment: I was just about to come answer my own question, but you beat me to it. Your way is a little more elegant than mine---I just added     `sh.Activate`

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching in your example is string `strSearch` but not `TOI Score`. change appropriate line into:

```
Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=strSearch,...
```

and so on...

Comment: I tried this and it fixed the strSearch from not being defined, but the search is not working now even though it works when I run it by itself. So now the error is that aCell is not defined